# Photo dictionary of things going wrong

Tags: contamination, problems, mistakes

Sometimes things don't go so well. Sometimes relaxing and having a homebrew doesn't quite do the trick. Sometimes it's not just going to fix itself.

It would be helpful to have some images to compare against as things go wrong. For this community wiki, each "answer" should be a type of issue, like contamination, with an image (or multiple images) that are good examples of the issue.

*Note: This is a community wiki. No one will gain reputation for up votes. Everyone can edit every answer*

Comment: All my beer has been perfect otherwise I'd contribute :-P

Comment: I don't think this is really the format for such a thing.  Perhaps we could create a tag that people could tag their questions with, or help improve searching for photos of contaminated beer?

Comment: You might consider starting an actual wiki for this, which you could organise effectively by theme, and cross link the hell out of.

Comment: I support the creation of a tag which would help searching for photos

Comment: Probably raise it on meta

Answer (score 8):

I really, really hate when this happens:

[image]
<sub>(source: [b3ta.com](http://www2.b3ta.com/host/creative/67175/1218670664/thumb.EmptyPintGlass.jpg))</sub>

I'm sure most of you know how to fix it.

Comment: Yep.  I hate dark colored coasters too.